# Detect innerHTML changes in iframe with Observer

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers

I am creating an extension for Chrome and I need to detect a change in the **innerHTML** that is **inside an iFrame**.

I made two examples:

- This works well (outside of the iFrame):

```js
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('#contador');
// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  console.log($('#contador').text());   
});
// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```

```html
<div id="contador"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Script for random number with 3 seconds interval -->
<script>
var myInterval = setInterval( function (){
  
var num = parseInt( Math.random()*100 )+1; 
  
  $('#contador').html( num ) ; 
  
}, 3000);
</script>
```

- And it doesn't work (inside the iFrame):
  (It returns: ***Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.*** in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1knoe6yL/))

```js
var iframe = window.frames[0];

// select the target node
var target = iframe.document.querySelector('#contador');
// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  console.log($('#contador').text());   
});
// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```

```html
<!-- iframe with script for random number hosted in 000webhost-->

<iframe src="https://ipaymobile.000webhostapp.com">
</iframe>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

***Note:** The page I'm accessing is this:*

https://xxxxx.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=%2F$pa_dashboard.do

And this is the iframe html:

```
<iframe id="gsft_main" allowfullscreen="true" main-pane="true" name="gsft_main" title="Fila de Atendimento | ServiceNow" aria-label="Conteúdo principal" src="$pa_dashboard.do" data-original-title="Conteúdo principal"></iframe>
```

If I click on the iframe src and open it in a new tab, open this link:

https://xxxxx.service-now.com/$pa_dashboard.do

Comment: iframe.document should be iframe.contentDocument

Comment: Note that if the iframe is cross-origin you can't access its contents. You'll have to declare a content script with `all_frames` ([more info](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#frames)) so it'll run inside that iframe, it'll be able to access frame's contents via `document` directly.

Comment: @wOxxOm I changed the ```iframe.document``` to ```iframe.contentDocument``` and now I have the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined

Comment: It means the iframe didn't yet load (you need to listen to `load` event on its element) or it's cross-origin.

Comment: @wOxxOm The error is gone, but the Observer does not return the value. See: https://jsfiddle.net/6r92dq4g/

Comment: The link contains the same incorrect code that tries to access `frame.document`. Note that jsfiddle hides all errors so you won't see something is wrong. Better not use it.

Comment: @wOxxOm I am not able to understand where the error is. Can you make an example in JSFiddle (or similar) please?

Comment: Someone to help?